# AWS : Migrate tables from RDS (postgreSQL) to DynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

What is the best way to perform a migration of an AWS RDS postgreSQL DB to DynamoDB?

[AWS Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) only seems to support MySQL in terms of dumping RDS to S3 or Redshift. (I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212957/need-strategy-advice-for-migrating-large-tables-from-rds-to-dynamodb) but it does not apply to postgreSQL I believe)

[AWS DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/dms/) also does not seem to support this kind of migration

Comment: The answer in the post you linked applies to all RDS databases, including PostgreSQL. Although to be honest you probably need to totally rethink your table schemas when you move to DynamoDB since it is a totally different type of database with totally different schema capabilities and restrictions, and totally different index requirements. I doubt this is going to be a simple migration, and I would expect to have to spend some time customizing a migration solution to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know. Its just a small part before processing for something we are trying. Those tables will be discarded after